# nginx server directive not allowed here issue (simple code)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration

I realize there's tons of similar issues like this out there, and I've looked at most of them, I'm building this on a VM for a "prove to myself I can do it" type of thing.

running nginx with Ubuntu core OS

anyway, here's the code:

```
server{
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
 }
```

ran check code on `nginx.conf` and came back free of errors.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your entire `nginx.conf`, then the `server` container should be enclosed within an `http` container:

```
http {
  ...
  server {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't very clear, this is a symbolically linked code file under sites-available and sites-enabled. Designed to give the user a 404 error if they look for a webpage I don't have i.e. (Not under the index or sites-available directories)